# fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware[0]

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

While my .NET Core application is running, I noticed the following line:

```
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware[0]
      An unhandled exception has occurred: Method 'Clone' in type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.Internal.SqlServerOptionsExtension' from assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer, Version=1.1.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' does not have an implementation. System.TypeLoadException: Method 'Clone' in type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.Internal.SqlServerOptionsExtension' from assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer, Version=1.1.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' does not have an implementation.
```

I'm just curious what's causing this error because my apps is still running fine despite the error message.

By the way, I'm using .NET Core 2.0.0 Preview 1 version.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware is just the middleware catching exceptions when nothing else in your program did

So your "real" exception is 
`Method 'Clone' in type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.Internal.SqlServerOptionsExtension' from assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer, ...' does not have an implementation`

By doing some googling with this exception, it seems to get down to support of your .Net Core version vs your EF Provider

If you want more information, you can:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-2.1#the-developer-exception-page Enable Developer Exception pages
- Log more information from EF (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-2.1#add-providers => enable in trace mode will get you more information)